# Adding PageViewController in the ContainerViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to add `pageviewcontroller` to my `containerviewcontroller`. But I do not know which segue needs to be used (`Show, Show Detail, Present Modally, Present As PopOver, Custom` ?).

[image]

**Optional:**

I know few stackoverflow fellows may complain, but I am leaving this section optional.

I could not able to find a good resources to use `pageviewcontroller` inside the `containerviewcontroller`. is there any good resources for recommendation? Is it recommended approach in terms of clean-cut design? If it is, I am going to take this design approach as an opportunity to learn.

Comment: see this for example https://www.mindstick.com/Articles/11892/uipageviewcontroller-sample-in-ios

Comment: Thanks a lot Anbu, I do not see storyboard segue in this tutorial? It seems he has added programatically.

Comment: Why contAiner ? you can use view controller http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/

Comment: Container view controllers are a way to combine the content from multiple view controllers into a single user interface. Container view controllers are most often used to facilitate navigation and to create new user interface types based on existing content. - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html

Comment: @Maulik, why dont you recommend using `containerViewController` ?

Comment: Becaz of easy to use. I Don't like use to container view in page view controller.@hotspring

Comment: ok, you do not have any arguments rather than you do not like to use or it seems difficult for you to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a container view to the scene, then remove its default embedded controller. Now control drag from the container view to pageviewcontroller and select `Embed` segue type. Also set identifier for the segue, like `embedPageViewControllerSegue`
[image: Like this]

Now, Back in your container view controller configure your destination pageviewcontroller like,

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "embedPageViewControllerSegue" {
        let pageviewController = segue.destination as! UIPageViewController
        //configure your pageview controller - set datasource, delegate, initial view controller etc
    }
}
```

Comment: then how could I able to add my components on the containerview using storyboard?

Comment: sorry I didn't get that.. Components in containerview?. You can use page view controllers datasource and delegate for setting up pageviewcontroller